# Adjusting number of visible items in multiple-select list

Tags: fields-attributes, qfield, widget

We created a value relation widget in our project, which contains many different selectable options. However, only 5 out of 25 options can be seen at once (see attached photo). Is there a way to expand the number of visible items of a multiple-select list in QField, so that one wouldn't need to scroll too much?
[image]